# @android:dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

quisiera saber por qué me bota error este parte de mi código en android versión "3.1.4". Si ya tengo en mi archivo "build.gradle" el "implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'"[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta dimensión se usaba en versiones antiguas para determinar la altura de la `action bar`, actualmente no existe.

```
<!-- Default height of an action bar. -->
<dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">56dp</dimen>
```

Puedes agregar este valor en tu archivo `dimens.mxl`. Si no existe este archivo, para crearlo lo realizas de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

crea un archivo llamado `dimens.xml` y agrega la entrada:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">56dp</dimen>   
</resources>
```

y obten la referencia de esta forma:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
```

Comment: WOW, gracias maestro. Un gran saludo "Jorgesys"